# Power Bi - how to filter and count zero values from 52 colums

Tags: powerbi

I have a table with 52 columns and I want to filter only zero values and count them from each column. I thought of doing it by adding a custom column but its very difficult to do for all the columns. Can someone please suggest to me how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

The table looks something like this,

[image]

Comment: Can you unpivot those columns in the query editor? That would be a much easier format to work with.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I did that but I get an error as "OLE DB or ODBC error:[Dataformat.error] We couldn't convert to number". So, I tried to change the data type to text but still its not working